# How to remove/hide the default sharepoint header and Navigation settings bar make it look like a normal webpage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have created a site for a webpage in my corporate sharepoint. How to remove the default sharepoint header and make it look like a normal webpage

I have tried navigating the look and feel options in site settings. But, I feel some options are not visible due to subscription limitations. Any answers or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove SharePoint site header completely, but you can hide it by following below steps:

1. Click on settings (gear icon) > Change the look > Navigation > turn OFF site navigation visibility > Save
2. Click on settings (gear icon) > Change the look > Header > Set Layout to "Minimal" > turn OFF site title visibility > Upload white transparent image as site logo and site thumbnail > Save

This will hide the site header. However, small/minimal white horizontal section at the top will be there which cannot be hidden using SharePoint out of the box options.

**References**:

1. [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)
2. [New Site Header Options in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/08/new-site-header-options-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/)
3. [SharePoint Header Site remove](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-header-site-remove/m-p/3691692)

Comment: Not the site header. I was trying to hide the main SharePoint header or customize it to include it in the site rather than a separate nav bar.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of which header you are talking about? If you are talking about the Office 365 ribbon at the top most side, there is no SharePoint out of the box way to hide it. Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297914/hiding-office-365-ribbon-in-sharepoint/297915#297915

Answer (score 0):

May be a simple way is to type an space instead of the Site Title! To do this:

- Go to Site Settings
- Click on "Title, description, and logo"
- Type an space in Title field (if you don't type an space, a backslash character will be shown instead of the site title!)
- Click OK

Cheers,
Hamid